# How does Craft know when to generate an Image Transform

Tags: image-transforms

I created an image transform called `teamImage`. My template code is below.

I want this transform to be created when I upload an image within a `Team` entry.

*`Team` has it's own asset folder.*

My questions is how does craft know when to create this transform and where in the directory does it create it?

```
{% for asset in entry.teamImage %}
    <a href="{{ entry.url }}">
         <img src="{{ asset.getUrl('teamImage') }}" alt="{{ asset.title }}" />
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Craft will make the image transform the first time the template is loaded in the browser and the `getUrl()` is called. The image will at first be saved in a temporary directory, then moved into a sub-directory in your assets folder. The subdirectory will be descriptively named according to the type of transform. For example, if my template calls for a 500 x 500 center-center crop at 75% quality, it will be saved in `/uploads/_500x500_crop_center-center_75/img.jpg`.

This works similarly when using a CDN like S3 or Google Cloud.

Comment: ok, that makes sense, but when I load the template in the browser the transform subfolder is not created.

I have tried updating my image assets index.

Comment: Do you have your transform defined in the template or in the control panel?  If it is in the template, you should not add quotes around the transform name: `{{ asset.getUrl(teamImage) }}`

Comment: I have it defined in the CP.

Comment: Ok! When you inspect the element in the browser, is it showing the original image url or does it look different? Make sure you have [devMode](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#devMode) on too to see if there are any other errors happening.

Comment: ok, got it sorted. my intended `entry` variable was actually `teamMember`. doh.

Comment: Ah. Glad you got it sorted out!

Comment: Also see this for reference: http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#generateTransformsBeforePageLoad

Comment: @AaronBerkowitz Your valuable explanation should go into the [docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/image-transforms.html).